# Express.js File Uploads

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm fairly new to express and am having problems with using express.bodyParser to to upload files. bodyParser works as expected with req.body, so it appears to be properly set up. I am running node 0.6.17 and express 2.5.8. Whenever I try to access req.files, it is undefined. Does anyone know what the cause of this issue is?

from app.js:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret: "string" }));
  app.use(flash());
  app.use( express.bodyParser() );
  app.use(expressValidator);
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

from index.js

```
app.get('/product/add', function(req, res) {
    res.render("add_products", {
      title: "Add Products",
            email: req.session.email || 'Sign In/Up',
      error: req.flash('error') || []
    });
});

app.post('/product/add', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.files) // prints undefined
var errors = generate_error_messages(req, 'product/add') || [];
if (errors.length > 0) {
  var errors_string_array = messages(errors);
  req.flash('error', errors_string_array);
  res.redirect('/product/add');
} else {
  ProductDatabase.save(req, function(err, docs) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
}
});
```

add_products.jade

```
  form(class='form-horizontal', method='post', action='/product/add')
    fieldset
      .control-group
        label(class='control-label', for="title") Product Title
        .controls
          input(type="text", class="input-xlarge", name="title")
      .control-group
        label(class='control-label', for="description") Description
        .controls
          textarea(class="input-xlarge", name="description", rows="5")
      .control-group
        label(class='control-label', for='auction_length') Auction Length
        .controls
          select(name='auction_length')
            option 1 day
            option 2 days
            option 5 days
      .control-group
        label(class='control-label', for="fileInput") Upload Image
        .controls
          input(class='input-file', name='fileInput', type='file')
      .form-actions
        input(type="submit", class="btn btn-primary") Sell Product
        a.btn(href='/') Cancel
```

Comment: Have you considered using Formidable?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {...} inside of the post route, but the program never ran the parse method.

Comment: Formidable is used by express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about
[connect-form](https://github.com/sdepold/connect-form)? That has worked better in my experience.

Comment: I tried that too, but it returned undefined just like bodyParser

Comment: In the form, set the enctype to "multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

u have a problem in add_products.jade file.

First line form tag should have enctype attribute.It should be like,

form(class='form-horizontal', method='post', action='/product/add',enctype='multipart/form-data')

to post a file u should have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

for simple uploading you just need these configuration:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/upload'));
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:__dirname + '/upload'}));
```

and in jade template:

```
form(method='post', action='/upload', enctype='multipart/form-data')
    input(name='file', type='file')
    input(type='submit')
```